# Visual studio project/solution compilation with only .net SDK (without installed VS)

Tags: visual-studio, compilation, project, azure, solution

Is it possible?
And if possible, is it possible to compile created in VS azure cloud project, having only .net35 and azure SDKs installed, also without VS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k6kkbsd.aspx) which comes with the .NET framework

Comment: Got it - compilation works. Sorry, i've asked a bit wrong question for azure cloud project - is it possible to _Publish_ azure cloud project? (In VS i click on cloudService project, select "Publish", and it generates ".cspkg" file which is to be deployed to azure hosting.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Azure SDK comes with a utility called [cspack.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd179470.aspx), which will create a .cspkg file for you.